# C++ Failure Testing for streams using libfiu

Tags: c++, error-handling, stream, posix, system-calls

I came across the libfiu tool for fault injection in posix calls in C
programs http://blitiri.com.ar/p/libfiu/ . 
I am unable to use this for fault injection in C++ streams.
I am specifically talking about the following sample program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<errno.h>
#include<cstdlib>
//#include<fiu-local.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if(argc < 2){
                std::cout << "Usage ./a.out <count>" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
        }
        try{
                int count = atoi(argv[1]);
                std::ofstream oss;
                char buf[20] = "samplestring";
                oss.exceptions( std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);
                std::cout << "Try to open outputstream" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "errno = " << errno << std::endl;
                oss.open("/k/8c5ae82f-8146-44e0-ac04-4cba79ee5e4c/myFile");
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        oss.write(buf, 20);
                //      std::cout << i <<  std::endl;
                }
        }catch(std::exception &e){
                std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "errno = " << errno << std::endl;
        }
}
```

If I try failing write() posix call using the following command:

```
fiu-run -x -c 'enable name=posix/io/rw/write,failinfo=5' ./a.out 10
```

It does not fail the oss.write() function [Line 22]. But using the
same command, I am able to fail the write() system call in the
following sample program:

```
  1 #include<unistd.h>
  2 #include<iostream>
  3 #include <sys/types.h>
  4 #include <sys/stat.h>
  5 #include <fcntl.h>
  6 #include <errno.h>
  7 #include <string.h>
  8
  9
 10 int main()
 11 {
 12         int fd = open("testfile", O_RDWR);
 13         int wc;
 14         if(fd < 0){
 15                 std::cout << "Error opening file " << errno << std::endl;
 16         }else{
 17                 std::cout << "FD open " << fd <<std::endl;
 18                 wc = write(fd , "Hello", 6);
 19                 int errCode = errno;
 20                 if(wc > 0){
 21                         std::cout << "Bytes written " << wc << std::endl;
 22                 }else{
 23                         std::cout << "Write Failed, ec returned "
<< strerror(errCode) << std::endl;
 24
 25                 }
 26         }
 27         close(fd);
 28         return 0;
 29 }
```

```
$ fiu-run -x -c 'enable name=posix/io/rw/write,failinfo=5' ./a.out 10
FD open 3
Write Failed, ec returned Input/output error
```

I did a strace on Example 1. It looks like both oss.write() and
write() both call the POSIX write() system call, but fiu seems to work for
Example 2 and not for Example 1.

Do I need additional settings for inducing errors for Example 1?

Is there a better way to inject failure in C++ streams for failure testing? Please advise.

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in source you post, it's hard to copy-paste it and compile for others.

Comment: I am unable to edit and save my changes, can you please help? I keep getting the error saying that the code is not formatted properly. 4 tabs are required.

Comment: Blocks of code needs to be indented by four spaces, then any formatting you want, but the four leading spaces is what tells the system the text is code. I've edited one of your code snippets, please see that edit.